# How to get part of a string in php

Tags: php, string

I have strings like:

```
t_est1_1
test213_4
tes_tsdfsdf_9
```

The common part of every string is the **LAST** underscore `_` character.

I need to get the string before this character.

```
t_est1_12 --> test1   
test213_4 --> test213
tes_tsdfsdf_9343 --> testsdfsdf
```

How can i achieve this in PHP?

Comment: http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the basic string functions [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 0):

http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php

```
$a = "abcdef_12345"
$b = array();
// $b[0] = "abcdef";
$b[0] = explode('_',$a,'1');
```

Comment: Check the question again.  The samples for desired outputs show that `explode` won't work.  At least not as simply as you describe.

Comment: Now that the OP has been edited, indeed explode won't work because we need to use the last occurrence of "_". (it wasn't mentioned a few minutes ago ?)

Comment: yes..the problem is that i have two "_" char. And i only need to cut the last one.

Comment: Still possible with `explode`. Given the examples, after `explode` on all underscores, `implode` on all elements except for the last element. However, a more clear approach would be `strpos` and `substr`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use preg_match function available in php

you need to write regular expression for that...

for example

to get this test1_12 ->> test1

```
$string='test1_12';
preg_match('((.+?)\_(.*))',$string,$match);
echo $match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a simple explode, array_slice and implode, also using explode and end, you can get the "id" that is the common part too:

```
$description = implode('', array_slice(explode('_', $data), 0, -1));
$id = end(explode('_', $data));
```

As many _ you will have, you'll still be able to expode on them and retrieve the last item containing your id and the first items (0 to -1) will contain your description...